# Linux V4L2 driver, video_register_device return invalid parameter?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, v4l2

I am trying to run some tutorial code on v4l2 driver from the web.

OS is Raspbian 11

The calling code is

```c
int ret1 = video_register_device(&vdev, VFL_TYPE_VIDEO, -1);
```

But on `insmod`, it returns -22 `EINVAL`.

I checked online source code of the function, it returns `EINVAL` only if vfl_type is wrong or `vdev.release` is null, but it seems none of it is the reason(checked).

Does the example code miss some step?

full code:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <media/videobuf2-vmalloc.h>
#include <media/v4l2-device.h>
#include <media/v4l2-ioctl.h>
#include <media/v4l2-ctrls.h>
#include <media/v4l2-fh.h>
#include <media/v4l2-event.h>
#include <media/v4l2-common.h>

//ar structure include v4l2_device
struct ar {
  struct v4l2_device v4l2_dev;
  struct video_device vdev;
};

//static ardev var
static struct ar ardev;

static int ar_querycap(struct file *file, void *priv,
                       struct v4l2_capability *vcap) {
  struct ar *ar = video_drvdata(file);
  /*fill
    struct v4l2_capability {
      __u8    driver[16];
      __u8    card[32];
      __u8    bus_info[32];
      __u32   version;
      __u32    capabilities;
      __u32    device_caps;
      __u32    reserved[3];
    };
    */
  strlcpy(vcap->driver, ar->vdev.name, sizeof(vcap->driver));
  strlcpy(vcap->card, "Mark test Card", sizeof(vcap->card));
  strlcpy(vcap->bus_info, "Mark test BUS", sizeof(vcap->bus_info));
  vcap->capabilities = V4L2_CAP_VIDEO_CAPTURE | V4L2_CAP_READWRITE;  // report capabilities

  printk(KERN_INFO "[mark]%s, %d, \n", __func__, __LINE__);

  return 0;
}

/****************************************************************************
*
* Video4Linux Module functions
*
****************************************************************************/

static const struct v4l2_file_operations ar_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = v4l2_fh_open,  // open /dev/video0 will enter here
    .release = v4l2_fh_release,  // close fd will enter here
    .unlocked_ioctl = video_ioctl2,  // need for ioctl
};

static const struct v4l2_ioctl_ops ar_ioctl_ops = {
    .vidioc_querycap = ar_querycap,  // ioctl VIDIOC_QUERYCAP will enter here
};

static int __init vivi_init(void) {
  struct ar *ar;
  struct v4l2_device *v4l2_dev;
  int ret;

  ar = &ardev;
  v4l2_dev = &ar->v4l2_dev;
  //init v4l2 name , version
  strlcpy(v4l2_dev->name, "arv", sizeof(v4l2_dev->name));
  v4l2_info(v4l2_dev, "Colour AR VGA driver %s\n", "0.0.1");  // output V4l2 info
  ret = v4l2_device_register(NULL, v4l2_dev);
  if (ret < 0) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Could not register v4l2_device\n");
    return ret;
  }

  //setup video
  strlcpy(ar->vdev.name, "Mark vivi Driver", sizeof(ar->vdev.name));
  ar->vdev.v4l2_dev = v4l2_dev;  // set V4l2_device address to video_device
  ar->vdev.fops = &ar_fops;  //v4l2_file_operations
  ar->vdev.ioctl_ops = &ar_ioctl_ops;  //v4l2_ioctl_ops
  ar->vdev.release = video_device_release_empty;
  // set_bit(V4L2_FL_USE_FH_PRIO, &ar->vdev.flags);
  video_set_drvdata(&ar->vdev, ar);

  {
    int ret1;
    ret1 = video_register_device(&ar->vdev, VFL_TYPE_VIDEO, -1);
    if (ret1 != 0) {  //3rd arg is device num, -1 means first free
      /* return -1, -ENFILE(full) or others */
      printk(KERN_INFO "[mark]%s, %d, video_register_device FAIL: %d \n", __func__, __LINE__, ret1);
      ret = ret1;
      goto out_dev;
    }
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO "[mark]%s, %d, module inserted\n", __func__, __LINE__);
  return 0;

out_dev:
  v4l2_device_unregister(&ar->v4l2_dev);
  video_unregister_device(&ar->vdev);

  return ret;
}

static void __exit vivi_exit(void) {
  struct ar *ar;
  ar = &ardev;

  printk(KERN_INFO "[mark]%s, %d, module remove\n", __func__, __LINE__);
  video_unregister_device(&ar->vdev);
  v4l2_device_unregister(&ar->v4l2_dev);
}

module_init(vivi_init);
module_exit(vivi_exit);

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Mark test module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Mark Yang");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

dmesg:

```
[21499.403742] CPU: 0 PID: 9463 Comm: insmod Tainted: G        WC O      5.10.63+ #1459
[21499.403752] Hardware name: BCM2835
[21499.403761] Backtrace: 
[21499.403813] [<c08746c0>] (dump_backtrace) from [<c0874a40>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[21499.403831]  r7:00000382 r6:00000009 r5:bf26ac78 r4:c0a70ae0
[21499.403853] [<c0874a20>] (show_stack) from [<c0877cb8>] (dump_stack+0x28/0x30)
[21499.403880] [<c0877c90>] (dump_stack) from [<c0022fe4>] (__warn+0xe8/0x110)
[21499.403893]  r5:bf26ac78 r4:bf2897a0
[21499.403915] [<c0022efc>] (__warn) from [<c0875054>] (warn_slowpath_fmt+0x68/0xd8)
[21499.403932]  r7:00000009 r6:bf26ac78 r5:00000382 r4:bf2897a0
[21499.404163] [<c0874ff0>] (warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<bf26ac78>] (__video_register_device+0x1494/0x2144 [videodev])
[21499.404186]  r9:bf341000 r8:c33599c0 r7:00000000 r6:c0bb3028 r5:ffffffff r4:bf341258
[21499.404405] [<bf2697e4>] (__video_register_device [videodev]) from [<bf3440bc>] (vivi_init+0xbc/0x1000 [v4l2step2])
[21499.404427]  r10:00000028 r9:bf341000 r8:c33599c0 r7:00000000 r6:c0bb3028 r5:00000000
[21499.404438]  r4:bf341200
[21499.404468] [<bf344000>] (vivi_init [v4l2step2]) from [<c000a138>] (do_one_initcall+0x4c/0x1e4)
[21499.404482]  r5:bf344000 r4:bf341000
[21499.404503] [<c000a0ec>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c009cfd0>] (do_init_module+0x6c/0x240)
[21499.404520]  r8:c33599c0 r7:c3359980 r6:00000002 r5:c6dfc0e0 r4:bf341000
[21499.404537] [<c009cf64>] (do_init_module) from [<c009f6f8>] (load_module+0x23d4/0x265c)
[21499.404551]  r6:00000002 r5:00000002 r4:cb421f30
[21499.404568] [<c009d324>] (load_module) from [<c009fbf8>] (sys_finit_module+0xc0/0xfc)
[21499.404586]  r10:00000000 r9:cb420000 r8:c00083e4 r7:00000003 r6:0002de04 r5:c0bb3028
[21499.404596]  r4:00000000
[21499.404613] [<c009fb38>] (sys_finit_module) from [<c0008240>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x28)
[21499.404625] Exception stack(0xcb421fa8 to 0xcb421ff0)
[21499.404640] 1fa0:                   00000000 00000002 00000003 0002de04 00000000 b6f41db4
[21499.404657] 1fc0: 00000000 00000002 b491c000 0000017b 00b3d868 00000002 bef9a7e4 00000000
[21499.404670] 1fe0: bef9a610 bef9a600 00023bc0 b6c3e9e0
[21499.404686]  r7:0000017b r6:b491c000 r5:00000002 r4:00000000
[21499.404697] ---[ end trace 764980d13fd4ad16 ]---
[21499.404710] [mark]vivi_init, 95, video_register_device FAIL: -22
```

Comment: It seems that you didn't set `ar->vdev.device_caps`

Comment: @dafnahaktana wow, it works, thank you!!